# Looking for differences btw. linear regression lines in R

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I'm trying to figure out how I can compare linear regressions (lines) to check if there are any significant differences in the slope of these regressions.

I've googled extensively, but couldn't work it out. I'd appreciate any help with this.

Here's the minimal working example:

```
# making a dataframe
x <- c(13.5, 2.8, 10.1, 5.8, 6.4, 12.5, 3.2, 8.9, 13.0)
y <- c(1.2, 3.2, 0.2, 1.9, 2.5, 0.6, 2.0, 0.4, 1.3)
z <- c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C")

df = data.frame(x, y, z)

df
#      x   y z
# 1 13.5 1.2 A
# 2  2.8 3.2 A
# 3 10.1 0.2 A
# 4  5.8 1.9 B
# 5  6.4 2.5 B
# 6 12.5 0.6 B
# 7  3.2 2.0 C
# 8  8.9 0.4 C
# 9 13.0 1.3 C

###############################################
# plotting the data
plot(log10(x) ~ log10(y), 
     col=c("blue","red","green")[unclass(z)], data = df,
     pch=20)


###############################################
# subsetting the data for making the regrssion lines
df.A <- subset(df, z == "A")
df.B <- subset(df, z == "B")
df.C <- subset(df, z == "C")

###############################################
# making and drawing the regression line for A
res.A=lm(log10(df.A$x) ~log10(df.A$y))

res.A
# Call:
#   lm(formula = log10(df.A$x) ~ log10(df.A$y))
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)  log10(df.A$y)  
#        0.8458        -0.3862 

# drawing the regression line A
abline(res.A, col= "blue", lty = 2)


###############################################
# making and drawing the regression line for B
res.B=lm(log10(df.B$x) ~log10(df.B$y))

res.B
# Call:
#   lm(formula = log10(df.B$x) ~ log10(df.B$y))
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)  log10(df.B$y)  
#        0.9688        -0.5271 

#drawing the regression line B
abline(res.B, col= "red", lty = 2)


###############################################
# making and drawing the regression line for C
res.C=lm(log10(df.C$x) ~log10(df.C$y))

res.C
# Call:
#   lm(formula = log10(df.C$x) ~ log10(df.C$y))
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)  log10(df.C$y)  
#        0.8586        -0.4330  

#drawing the regression line C
abline(res.C, col= "green", lty = 2)
```

[image: Resulting plot with regression lines]

Thanks!

Comment: To me it is not clear what you are asking. Could you please improve the question by describing (well, if possible) your goal? thanks.

Comment: I want to check if the slopes of the regressions differ significantly or not. Hope that helps.

Comment: why you just don't extract the coefficient from both models with `coef`  and check them ?

Comment: How do I check them?

Comment: I don't think it matters if the intercept vary, as I'm only interested in the differences in the slopes? I heard about using a dummy variable, but couldn'd figure out how to use it.

Comment: This is doing my head in.

Comment: But regression lines with different intecepts can have the same slope, can't they? Meaning they would run paralell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare a model with one slope and 3 intercepts to one with 3 slopes and 3 intercepts using `anova`:

```
fm1 <- lm(log10(y) ~ z + log10(x), df)
fm3 <- lm(log10(y) ~ z + log10(x)/z, df)
anova(fm1, fm3)
```

giving:

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: log10(y) ~ z + log10(x)
Model 2: log10(y) ~ z + log10(x)/z
  Res.Df     RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
1      5 0.72132                           
2      3 0.64793  2  0.073387 0.1699 0.8513
```

so the difference among the slopes is not significant.

Note that we  only have a small amount of data so the differences would have to be sufficiently large for this small set to find such differences significant.

Comment: Follow up question: How would I have to proceed to then extract which slope is different from which (assuming the anova has revealed significant differences)?

Comment: Ignoring multiple testing problems, create new models in which two of the slopes are the same and the other differs and compare such models to `fm1` (or to `fm3` depending on your purpose) to determine if they are significantly different.  e.g. A model with 3 intercepts and 2 slopes with slope of B being different `is.B <- df$z == 'B'; fmB <- lm(log10(y) ~ z + log10(x)/is.B, df); anova(fm1, fmB)`

Comment: `anova` cannot be used to compare a model based on one set of data to a model using a different set of data (such as a subset).

Comment: Yes, modulo multiple testing problems, that is OK since both use the same `df.A.B`.  If you plot them it will be obvious which might be different and which might be the same.  From your plot it seems that the red one might be different but the other two are likely the same; however, with this little data it might not be enough to show that even the red one is different.

Comment: Thank you, but by doing this the before indicated significance among the slopes disappears from my data. I'll put together a new question with a working example that reflects this and will leave a link to it here later today.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in the answer, if you don't have enough data then you won't be able to detect significance.